# Is the Big O notation the same for memoized recursion versus iteration?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, recursion

I am using a simple example off the top of my head here

```
function factorial(n)
   if n==1 return 1
   else return n*factorial(n-1)

function factorial(n)
    result = 1
    for i = 1 to n
        result *= n
    return result
```

Or functions that are recursive and have memoization vs. dynamic programming where you iterate over an array and fill in values, etc.

I know that sometimes recursion is bad because you can run out of memory (tail recursion?) with the heap (or stack?), but does any of this affect O notation?

Does a recursive memoized algorithm have the same O notation / speed as the iterative version?

Comment: given `n` how many times do you call `*` ?  O() does not notate speed, it notates how speed varies with regard to `n`

Comment: you want to memoize _and_ use recursion? well, that will blow up in space. i would think in any case it would still be O(n) but slower, meaning that both would scale equivalently, but the recursive method would be slower for any given value of n.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when considering an algorithm's complexity we would consider space and time complexity separately.

Two similar algorithms, one recursive, and one converted to be not recursive will often have the same time complexity, but differ in space complexity.

In your example, both factorial functions are O(n) time complexity, but the recursive version is O(n) space complexity, versus O(1) fort he iterative version.

This difference isn't universal. Memoization take space, and sometimes the space it takes up is comparable or even greater than the stack space a recursive version uses.

Comment: Are you sure tail recursion is O(N) space when optimized?

Comment: Its certainly possible that any given instance of a recursive program that is using tail recursion could be optimized by your compiler for you, so you cant be sure it will take up O(N) space when run. Of course, sitting here I tend to assume people are using debug builds not high optimization builds, so the chances are quite as high there.

Comment: @Glenn to expand on that, I just wrote the above and compiled it with g++ (4.7.3). It did not do the optimization by default, crashing when I gave a modest input (10k), while with the O2 flag, it optimizes a integer tail recursion, but not when I switched to calculating doubles.

Comment: +1 for testing it, it's very odd to have to include compiler flags to calculate O().

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of what you're using to store memoized values, the two will have the same order of complexity. For example, using a `dict` in Python (which has (amortized) `O(1)` insert/update/delete times), using memoization will have the same order (`O(n)`) for calculating a factorial as the basic iterative solution.

However, just as one can talk about time complexity, one can also talk about space complexity. Here, the iterative solution uses `O(1)` memory, while the memoized solution uses `O(n)` memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about asymptotically time complexcity, of course it's the same cause you are using the same algorithm.
I guess what you really care about is performance. For C like language, it is possible that recursion will be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to actually *use* the memoized results?
Besides the fact that the order is the same (both scale equivalently), for a single run of factorial, memoizing is useless - you'll walk through a series of arguments, and none of them will repeat - you'll never use your saved memoized values, meaning that you'll have wasted space and time storing them, and not gotten any speed-ups anywhere else.

However... once you have your memoized dictionary, then subsequent factorial calls will be less than O(n), and will depend on the history. I.E. if you calculate factorial(10), then values of factorial between 10 and 0 are available for instant lookup - O(1). If you calculate factorial(15), it does 15*14*13*12*11*factorial(10), which it just looks up, for 6 multiplies total (instead of 15).

However, you could also create a lookup dict for the iterative version, I guess. Memoization wouldn't help as much - in that case, factorial(10) would only store the result for 10, not all the results down to 0, because that's all the argument list would see. But, the function could store those intermediate values to the memoization dict directly.